# Prevent hotlinking a 1 specific URL but allow on all others

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I know the htaccess method for preventing hotlinking on every site aside of your own domain but i need something more advanced if possible

I would like to allow access on my personal server and all other sites , but yet pinpoint out a few select sites and ban them from hotlinking

pretty much i want to ALLOW ALL and deny a specific IP or URL

Allow : 
mywebdomain.com
allothersites.com

Prevent :
donotallowthissite.com
donotallowthissite2.com

is this possible , if so can you share how to achieve it ty ?

I am currently using this to allow access to hotlink all my files to a 3rd party server with multiple servers , but its too confusing to keep adding new servers and direct ids to each site , so i want to allow ALL to hotlink from my server, but when i find someone copyrighting my material i want to block that site and id specifically

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?nitrografixx.com [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?www(2|32|26|3|29|7|5).myfantasyleague.com.+(15982|21316|51396|47164|64314|43757|43757|63884|72807|54905)$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?www(2|32|26|3|29|7|5).myfantasyleague.com.+(15982|21316|51396|47164|64314|43757|43757|63884|72807|54905).+$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?football(2|32|26|3|29|7|5).myfantasyleague.com.+(15982|21316|51396|47164|64314|43757|43757|63884|72807|54905)$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?football(2|32|26|3|29|7|5).myfantasyleague.com.+(15982|21316|51396|47164|64314|43757|43757|63884|72807|54905).+$ [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?football.+.myfantasyleague.com.+(mb|site_news|choose_schedule) [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?football.+.myfantasyleague.com.+(h2h|seed_playoff_teams|playoff_schedule_setup|general_playoff_setup|transaction_setup|randomize_schedule|set_draft_order|change_draft_pick|adjust|delete_adjustments|new_predraft|calculate|waivers|rearrange_schedule|accounting|delete_transactions|trades|history|save_award|delete_accounting|submit_lineups|franchise_setup|options|message|custom_waiver_order|commish_email_setup|invite_franchise_owners|league_calendar_setup|fee_setup|standings_setup|division_conference_setup|select_packaged_waiver_rules)$ [NC]

RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Comment: yes, it is possible. if you can update your question to show what you are trying that's not working i might be able to help.

Comment: i haven't tried anything yet , as i've googled everywhere and cant seem to find a solution , only methods of allowing specific sites to hotlink, but nothing to prevent specific sites from doing so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://(www\.)?donotallowthissite\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://(www\.)?donotallowthissite2\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Using the sites you want to *block* and using the `[OR]` flag.

So any other sites other than the two listed in the conditions will not hit the rule.

Comment: This solution doesn't answer the question. RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$ blocks all empty headers while the question is to block specific domain names. Not those named domain name AND every website without headers.