# Prevent hotlinking specific domain

Tags: .htaccess, hotlinking

I'm trying to block this specific website that hotlinks to my images. Until now I haven't managed. I have tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://resepmakanan.id [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|png|gif)$ – [NC,F,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://resepmakanan\.id/ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|png|gif)$ – [NC,F,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://resepmakanan\.id/ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ http://i.imgur.com/xxxxxx.jpg [NC,F,L]
```

Could this method not work because there are headers sent via Cloudflare?

Comment: Possible duplicate question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846290/prevent-hotlinking-a-1-specific-url-but-allow-on-all-others

Comment: The question is maybe the same but the answer is wrong. The code provided blocks all urls with empty headers. I just want to block the specific domain name.